# Which style of Ruby string quoting do you favour?

Tags: ruby, string

Which style of Ruby string quoting do you favour? Up until now I've always used `'single quotes'` unless the string contains certain escape sequences or interpolation, in which case I obviously have to use `"double quotes"`.

However, is there really any reason not to just use double quoted strings everywhere?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Don't use double quotes if you have to escape them. And don't fall in "single vs double quotes" trap. Ruby has excellent support for arbitrary delimiters for string literals:

Mirror of Site - https://web.archive.org/web/20160310224440/http://rors.org/2008/10/26/dont-escape-in-strings

Original Site - 
http://rors.org/2008/10/26/dont-escape-in-strings

Answer (score 31):

I always use single quotes unless I need interpolation.

Why? It looks nicer. When you have a ton of stuff on the screen, lots of single quotes give you less "visual clutter" than lots of double quotes.

I'd like to note that this isn't something I deliberately decided to do, just something that I've 'evolved' over time in trying to achieve nicer looking code.

Occasionally I'll use %q or %Q if I need in-line quotes. I've only ever used heredocs maybe once or twice.

Answer (score 28):

Like many programmers, I try to be as specific as is practical. This means that I try to make the compiler do as little work as possible by having my code as simple as possible. So for strings, I use the simplest method that suffices for my needs for that string.

```
<<END
For strings containing multiple newlines, 
particularly when the string is going to
be output to the screen (and thus formatting
matters), I use heredocs.
END

%q[Because I strongly dislike backslash quoting when unnecessary, I use %Q or %q
for strings containing ' or " characters (usually with square braces, because they
happen to be the easiest to type and least likely to appear in the text inside).]

"For strings needing interpretation, I use %s."%['double quotes']

'For the most common case, needing none of the above, I use single quotes.'
```

My first simple test of the quality of syntax highlighting provided by a program is to see how well it handles all methods of quoting.

Answer (score 11):

I use single quotes unless I need interpolation.  The argument about it being troublesome to change later when you need interpolation swings in the other direction, too: You have to change from double to single when you found that there was a # or a \ in your string that caused an escape you didn't intend.

The advantage of defaulting to single quotes is that, in a codebase which adopts this convention, the quote type acts as a visual cue as to whether to expect interpolated expressions or not.  This is even more pronounced when your editor or IDE highlights the two string types differently.

I use %{.....} syntax for multi-line strings.

Answer (score 8):

I usually use double quotes unless I specifically need to disable escaping/interpolation.

Answer (score 6):

I see arguments for both:

For using mostly double quotes:

- The [github ruby style guideline](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) advocates always using double quotes:

[image]

- It's easier to search for a string foobar by searching for "foobar" if you were consistent with quoting. However, I'm not. So I search for ['"]foobar['"] turning on regexps.

For using some combination of single double quotes:

- Know if you need to look for string interpolation.
- Might be slightly faster (although so slight it wasn't enough to affect the github style guide).

Answer (score 5):

I used to use single quotes until I knew I needed interpolation. Then I found that I was wasting a lot of time when I'd go back and have to change some single-quotes to double-quotes. Performance testing showed no measurable speed impact of using double-quotes, so I advocate always using double-quotes.

The only exception is when using sub/gsub with back-references in the replacement string. Then you should use single quotes, since it's simpler.

```
mystring.gsub( /(fo+)bar/, '\1baz' )
mystring.gsub( /(fo+)bar/, "\\1baz" )
```

Answer (score 1):

I use single quotes unless I need interpolation, or the string contains single quotes.

However, I just learned the arbitrary delimiter trick from Dejan's answer, and I think it's great. =)

Answer (score 1):

Single quote preserve the characters inside them. But double quotes evaluate and parse them. See the following example:

```
"Welcome #{@user.name} to App!"
```

Results:

> Welcome Bhojendra to App!

But,

```
'Welcome #{@user.name} to App!'
```

Results:

> Welcome #{@user.name} to App!