# ruby coding convention for single or double quoting your strings

Tags: ruby, string, syntax, convention

I had a good look around but I couldn't find the **convention** on how to use quotes for strings.  I know the difference between the two, but everywhere I see good code with double quotes where the singles are enough.  Therefor, I can't recognize any pattern.  I'm asking this because I'd like to start contributing to open-source and I'd like to get a good habit since the beginning.  I rather use the single quotes as much as possible, also to strengthen my confidence with the difference between the two.

Comment: I am recently embracing [github ruby styleguide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby), string conventions at the bottom

Comment: Now I'm using [Airbnb Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/ruby).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is a strong convention within the entire community. From what I have seen, there seems to be a bias towards ignoring single quotes altogether and always using double quotes. In some circles, that *is* even a convention, but a localized one, not one for the whole community.

Personally, whenever I have several different ways to express the same thing, I tend to use those different ways to convey different semantics. (For example, I use curly braces vs. `do`/`end` in blocks to distinguish between blocks that are used for their side effects and blocks that are used for their return value.)

So, I only use double quotes when I *actually* want to use string interpolation or escaping, otherwise I use single quotes. That way, when I see a string I can immediately tell that there's no funny business going on, and there's no code hidden inside of it.

I am pragmatic, though. I very much prefer `"It's a string!"` over `'It\'s a string!'` or `%q[It's a string!]`.

Answer (score 14):

What you probably already know:

- Single quotes are just fine for simple strings.
- If you need to evaluate anything inside the string, you'll need double quotes.

There's [no significant performance difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836467/is-there-a-performance-gain-in-using-single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-ruby).

Using double quotes is helpful so you can use apostrophes without having to worry about escaping them inside the string thus making the string look 'prettier' in the code. Think `"Don't do that"` vs `'Don\'t do that'`

There's a line of thought that states that [you should never escape in strings](http://rors.org/2008/10/26/dont-escape-in-strings). If you need single quotes and double quotes inside your string, you are better off using a heredoc or flexible quotes. In the end, I'd let that guide what you need to use when coding if evaluating ruby code inside the string is not a concern.