# Convert array of strings to joined strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Input:

```
 array = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Desired output:

```
'A', 'B', 'C'
```

I'm using [legato](https://github.com/tpitale/legato) gem to chain google analytics filters. My method call looks like this:

```
response = KeywordRevenueData.results(profile, self.options).for_keywords(array)
```

I thought this would work,

```
array.map(&:inspect).join(", ")
```

but for some reason it doesn't.

**EDIT:**
It works fine when I put the literal strings in the method call:

```
response = KeywordRevenueData.results(profile, self.options).for_keywords("A", "B", "C")
```

single or double quotes seem to work fine if they are literals in the method call

Comment: This works, but it produces string with double-quotes inside: `'"A", "B", "C"'`

Comment: Included a working example. Can't figure this out for the life of me

Comment: Oh, then you just need to use . for_keywords(*array)

Comment: @SergeyBolgov: make that an answer

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! What does that do anyway? Make that an answer please so I can mark it as correct

Comment: That's the standard language feature to pass array items as method arguments. E.g. see here http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_methods.html#UC

Comment: [*"'A", "B", "C'"].join("','") => "'A','B','C'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use * to pass array elements as arguments:

```
response = KeywordRevenueData.results(profile, self.options).for_keywords(*array)  # Note the *
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use :

```
array.map{|l| "'" + l + "'"}.join(", ")
```

if you need to force the presence of surrounding quotes

This answer also has interesting suggestions :

- [How to improve code that quotes all array elements with `'` and returns a string containing all those quoted and comma-separated elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647327/how-to-improve-code-that-quotes-all-array-elements-with-and-returns-a-string)