# Double quoted strings in schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

It may be a bit trivial question, but always bothered me:

Are there any specific reasons for Rails to use double quoted strings instead of single quoted strings (as rubocop suggests) in schema.rb?

Comment: Because single quoted strings are not actually faster. The single quoted strings cop is mostly a piece of opinionated BS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836467/is-there-a-performance-gain-in-using-single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-ruby

Comment: Another answer in the same post says because it follows convention.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836467/is-there-a-performance-gain-in-using-single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-ruby#answer-1836838

Comment: Have you ever looked at `puts 'pancakes'.inspect`? `String#inspect` uses double quotes `#inspect` is a super easy way to deal with escaping in a string that is getting dumped into Ruby source code.

Comment: To be honest, I was not thinking about performance benefits, but the semantic benefits. When I see a double quote, I kind of expect a string interpolation or something interesting, etc. Maybe, it's just me! :) @max

Rubocop creator Bozdihar Batsov seems to agree too: https://www.viget.com/articles/just-use-double-quoted-ruby-strings#comment-1810997001

Comment: I have never seen a schema.rb that used double quoted strings to escape something/anything. I guess, I need to read more code. :) @muistooshort

Comment: That's because most people will be working with reasonable names in their database but AR can't really assume that all the table, column, constraint, ... names are reasonable. I'm with you on using double quoted strings as a signal that escaping or interpolation is coming but a lot of Ruby people use double quotes because that's probably what they learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `schema.rb` is using double quotes is that most of the formatting is done by calling `#inspect` on a number of predefined strings, e.g.:

```
# schema_dumper.rb:91
stream.puts "  enable_extension #{extension.inspect}"
```

And [`String#inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-inspect) prints the string with surrounding double quotes, i.e.:

```
"foo".inspect
#=> "\"foo\""
```

That said, RuboCop is there to catch human mistakes, so there's no need to include files generated by the framework, which are not meant to be edited manually. (You would still want to inspect application files created using the Rails generators.)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may find it useful to exclude the schema file from Rubocop's inspections by adding it to the `.rubocop.yml` file:

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - db/schema.rb
```