# Single quoted Ruby strings -- inconsistent escaping

Tags: ruby, string, escaping

Why do the following strings give me the same output in the Ruby interpreter?

```
  'f:\new'
  'f:\\new'
```

Both strings result in: `"f:\\new"`. I was expecting the second string to display `"f:\\\\new"` (if not that, then the first one should have shown `"f:\new"`)

Comment: I do not see the difference in your two input strings. Perhaps you mistyped.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby but I guess the first is detected as an incorrect use of backslash (in a single-quote string, it should have been followed by backslash or single quote), so the backslash is preserved...

Comment: @murgatroid99, do you see the difference now? (There was an SO formatting error.)

Comment: @murgatroid99 :- I edit the question now check it.
@Vulcan Eager :- Please check if i correctly edit or not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backslashes in Single quoted strings vs. Double quoted strings in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648156/backslashes-in-single-quoted-strings-vs-double-quoted-strings-in-ruby). In particular, look at [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single%5Fquotes) that was linked in the accepted answer.

Comment: @mikej, Not the same question. The devil is in the details.

Comment: @Salil, The edit shows the difference now

Comment: @Vulcan OK, sorry if I was a bit close-trigger happy :) looks like your question is a more specific version of the general question. The *reason* is the same as the one given in that question though: In a single quoted string \\ becomes \ and \' becomes '. Everything else is left alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single-quoted strings support only two escape sequences: `\'` and `\\`

That's why in your first example `\n` is not treated as new-line char: it's not in the list.