# Ruby - Making a newline within usage of gsub

Tags: ruby

I'm a bit stuck on this issue. I'm trying to make a newline using '\n'. I'm opening a file, then replacing the text, then writing it back as an html file:

```
replace = text.gsub(/aaa/, 'aaa\nbbb')

But this results in:
aaa\nbbb

I'm trying to make do:
aaa
bbb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to read:[`Backslashes in Single quoted strings vs. Double quoted strings in Ruby?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/648156/128421).

Answer (score 4):

In single-quoted strings a backslash is just a backslash (except if it precedes another backslash or a quote). Use double quotes: "aaa\nbbb" .