# How do I eval multiple lines of code in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
eval('puts "ff"\nputs "ff"')
```

I tried to use two expressions in one eval but it doesn't execute?

How do I do this? I want to know because I want to dynamically execute partial code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
eval('puts "ff";puts "ff"')
```

Answer (score 8):

With heredoc syntax. File and line number are passed to give reference information in back traces.

```
eval(<<-CODE, __FILE__, __LINE__ +1 )
  some(:ruby);
  code
  # and comments
CODE
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it works better for large multiline statements and facilitates debugging. Nice one!

Answer (score 5):

```
eval("puts 'ff'\nputs 'ff'")
```

also works. `'\n'` gets treated as literally a slash and an n, because single quotes work differently to double quotes.

Comment: Really? Would appreciate if you could point to some documentation? I thought that interchanging quotes didn't really matter ?

Comment: @Zabba: You can try it in irb, or you can look at documentation mentioned at [Backslashes in Single quoted strings vs. Double quoted strings in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648156/backslashes-in-single-quoted-strings-vs-double-quoted-strings-in-ruby)

Answer (score 4):

I use this:

```
eval %{
  puts 'ff'
  puts 'hello'
}
```