# Prefer %w(...) to a literal array?

Tags: ruby

While entering a simple literal array of strings in to RubyMine:

```
cols =
[
  "Col1",
  "Col2"
]
```

RubyMine complained that I should prefer to use `%w` over a literal array:

```
cols = %w(Col1 Col2)
```

It presented a link to a Ruby Style Guide ([here](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#collections)), which said:

> Prefer %w to the literal array syntax when you need an array of
>   strings.

```
# bad
STATES = ['draft', 'open', 'closed']

# good
STATES = %w(draft open closed)
```

I can see how the `%w` provides potentially more concise code.  Aside from brevity, is there any reason to prefer one method over the other?

Comment: Well the guide linked is quite opinionated and I don't think people will actually follow every single rule that are described. I don't think there's a rule telling anyone not to use literal arrays, IMO it's really a matter of taste

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto: That would be consistent with many style guides I've seen over the years.  Since it wasn't just some random style guide I stumbled across but the IDE itself suggesting it, I wondered if there was any meat to this assertion that I should prefer `%w` -- not that an IDE saying "do ABC" means I should do ABC...

Comment: Referring to the benchmark results I posted, I think the advantage to using `%w` is it results in a cleaner definition, which doesn't take as much maintenance. Maintenance is the big cost over the long term.

Comment: @theTinMan:  This would appear to be the only factor.

Comment: By the way: both are literal arrays.

Comment: @ jorg: is there any difference? Can you elaborate?

Comment: This question should not have beeen closed.  It is a specific, answerable question.  It is not subject to debate.  There either *is* or *is not* a difference between a literal array and an array declared with the `%w` syntax.

Comment: The fact that it's not a comma-separated list makes for simpler diffs.  When you add "Col3" to your list, you will have to modify the "Col2" line to put a comma at the end.  With the %w syntax, all you have to do is insert a single line.  That'll make it easier to both follow changes and solve merge conflicts.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Voila!, one benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 1_000_000
Benchmark.bm(11) do |b|
  b.report('%w') { n.times { %w[a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z] } }
  b.report('explicit') { n.times { ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'] } }
  b.report('numerics') { n.times { [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26] } }
end

                  user     system      total        real
%w            2.590000   0.000000   2.590000 (  2.591225)
explicit      2.590000   0.000000   2.590000 (  2.584781)
numerics      0.300000   0.000000   0.300000 (  0.309161)

                  user     system      total        real
%w            2.590000   0.000000   2.590000 (  2.591516)
explicit      2.590000   0.000000   2.590000 (  2.584155)
numerics      0.300000   0.000000   0.300000 (  0.308896)

                  user     system      total        real
%w            2.590000   0.000000   2.590000 (  2.592848)
explicit      2.590000   0.000000   2.590000 (  2.585558)
numerics      0.300000   0.000000   0.300000 (  0.308570)
```

I added the "numerics" array test because I suspected that `%w` is faster than using explicit strings due to testing for stringiness. `%w` doesn't need to do that, because it assumes everything is a string. After running it three times it's a wash as far as dealing with strings. Numbers rule, strings drool, and all that.

---

The previous benchmarks were run using Ruby 1.9.3-p286 on my system at work. I tested again using my old MacBook Pro at home, using Ruby 1.8.7-p358, so the following numbers are slower due to the differences in the hosting hardware, plus running an older Ruby:

```
                user     system      total        real
%w           3.070000   0.000000   3.070000 (  3.080983)
explicit     3.100000   0.000000   3.100000 (  3.093083)
numerics     0.950000   0.040000   0.990000 (  0.990535)

                user     system      total        real
%w           3.080000   0.010000   3.090000 (  3.076787)
explicit     3.090000   0.000000   3.090000 (  3.089246)
numerics     0.950000   0.030000   0.980000 (  0.989579)

                user     system      total        real
%w           3.080000   0.000000   3.080000 (  3.073877)
explicit     3.090000   0.000000   3.090000 (  3.091576)
numerics     0.950000   0.030000   0.980000 (  0.989132)
```

On 1.8.7, `%w` was a tiny bit faster consistently, which probably gave rise to the speed-rumors.

Comment: +1: Nice.  Learned at least 3 things here.

Comment: Both are *exactly the same thing*. If there even *was* any performance difference, it could *only* be during *parsing*. There *cannot* possibly be any *runtime* performance difference, because both are the *exact same thing*. Since the entire file is parsed *before* the benchmark is even started, the entire benchmark is meaningless. You would need to use `eval` or `load` or something like that to delay the parsing until after the benchmark has started.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You assert they are the exact same thing; but that's only true with a _sufficiently smart compiler_. %w{...} is always an array of literals, while `[...]` can be an array of literals or an array of expressions or a mix.  The compiler can analyze the array after parsing to understand it's an array of literals and therefore fully construct it at code generation time, but that's not a completely trivial optimization one should always assume you get without documentation, testing or code inspection.

Comment: @_the Tin Man_ thank you very much, the light at the end of my goals is getting brighter thanks to people like you.

Comment: @dbenhur: There is no need for a smart compiler here. On both JRuby and Rubinius, both pieces of code get parsed into the *exact same* AST, *before* they even hit the compiler proper. On YARV, the ASTs are *slightly* different, but the generated bytecode is identical: `putstring 'a'; putstring 'b'; putstring 'c'; newarray 3;`. Note that the YARV compiler is very much *not* a SSC, on the contrary: it's a pretty dumb compiler.

Comment: Does *everyone* in the [ruby] tag use *so many* ... *italics*?

Comment: "Does everyone in the [ruby] tag use so many ... italics?". Yes. It's a _snake_case_ thing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ruby implementations are pretty simplistic.  I'm not even sure whether mri does simple compile time constant expression evaluation.  My point was that one couldn't assume that %w{} and [literals] would both compile to the same code and data without actually investigating.  You repeatedly assert that they do but have not demonstrated it by posting pointers to the compiler code which makes it clear, or showing us a sample AST/bytecode output that demonstrates their equivalence. Belittling an attempt to investigate via benchmark without demonstrating your assertion is just annoying.