# How do I download/write file into a certain directory?

Tags: ruby, file-io

How can I specify the download directory? I tried this:

```
open("D:\Downloads" + filename, 'wb') do |io|
  response.read_body do |chunk|
    io.write chunk
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work. I don't even know in which directory the file is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Quote your path well. Also I think you need to add another `\`:

```
open("D:\\Downloads\\" + filename, 'wb') do |io|
  response.read_body do |chunk|
    io.write chunk
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the File classes' ability to [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-split) and [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-join) paths:

```
open(File.join("D:/Downloads", filename), 'wb')
```

[`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-join) and [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-split) are aware of the path separators and will do the right thing for you.

For instance:

```
filename = 'foo'

"D:\Downloads" + filename # => "D:Downloadsfoo"
File.join("D:\Downloads", filename) # => "D:Downloads/foo"
```

With Ruby it isn't necessary to use reverse-slashes (back-slash) in file-names on Windows. Ruby is smart enough to know the code is running on Windows, and automatically convert from forward-slashes to reverse-slashes if necessary.

See the [IO documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html):

> Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb". When specifying a Windows-style filename in a Ruby string, remember to escape the backslashes:

```
"c:\\gumby\\ruby\\test.rb"
```

> Our examples here will use the Unix-style forward slashes; File::ALT_SEPARATOR can be used to get the platform-specific separator character.

Now, look at the above sample code for using `File.join`. You're using `"D:\Downloads"` which gets converted to `D:Downloads` because of Ruby's double-quoted string interpreting `\D` as an attempt to escape `D` in error. As a result Ruby removes the single back-slash resulting in `"D:Downloads"`, making what you intended to be an absolute path into a relative one, which would be rooted at the current directory when the code was run. Being aware that you don't need to use reverse-slashes removes the problem entirely allowing you to write `"D:/Downloads"` and make you, and Ruby, happy.

Alternatively, you could have used single-quotes like `'D:\Downloads'`, which Ruby would have happily accepted and understood to mean `D:\\Downloads`, but, again, given the above knowledge that you don't have to mess with back-slashes, makes it a moot-point.

"[Backslashes in single quoted strings vs. double quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648156/backslashes-in-single-quoted-strings-vs-double-quoted-strings-in-ruby)" would be good additional reading for you.

Comment: `D:Downloads/foo` could mean the current directory in `D:` + `Downloads/foo`, and not exactly the same as `D:/Downloads/foo`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's why I said "making what you intended to be an absolute path into a relative one, which would be rooted at the current directory when the code was run."