# Match a word with backslash

Tags: ruby, regex

I am struggling to write a Ruby regexp that will match all words which: starts with 2 or 3 letters, then have backslash (`\`) and then have 7 or 8 letters and digits. The expression I use is like this:

```
p "BFD\082BBSA".match %r{\A[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,8}\z}
```

But each time this code returns `nil`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try as below :

```
'BFD\082BBSA'.match %r{\A[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\\[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,8}\z} 
 # => #<MatchData "BFD\\082BBSA">
 #or
"BFD\\082BBSA".match %r{\A[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\\[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,8}\z}
 # => #<MatchData "BFD\\082BBSA">
```

Read this also - [Backslashes in Single quoted strings vs. Double quoted strings in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648156/backslashes-in-single-quoted-strings-vs-double-quoted-strings-in-ruby)

Comment: It works! Do not tell me that the problem was with quotes... :D.

Comment: I think `\0` is treated as `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you actually have no backslash in your string, just a null Unicode character:

```
"BFD\082BBSA"
# => "BFD\u000082BBSA"
```

So you just have to escape the backslash in the string:

```
"BFD\\082BBSA"
# => "BFD\\082BBSA"
```

Moreover, as others pointed out, `\/` will match a forward slash, so you have to change `\/` into `\\`:

```
"BFD\\082BBSA".match(/\A[a-z]{2,3}\\[a-z0-9]{7,8}\z/i)
# => #<MatchData "BFD\\082BBSA">
```

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to match the backward slash, but you are matching forward slash. Please change the RegEx to

```
[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\\[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,8}
```

Note the `\\` instead of `\/`. Check the RegEx at work, [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/QwDafdPoB7)

Comment: Yeap, I still get nil :/

Comment: It is weird... on rubular it works but in "pure" ruby I get nil as return (ruby name_of_script.rb in console)