# is it possible to escape character within single quotes in ruby?

Tags: ruby, escaping, special-characters, quotes

I just faced this question in interview. Is it possible to escape character within single quotes in ruby?

The confusion is in following code

```
puts '\\'   # Output: \
puts '\n'   # Output: \n
```

It seems that backword slash is escaped but the newline character isn't.

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648156/backslashes-in-single-quoted-strings-vs-double-quoted-strings-in-ruby) but I am not asking about difference between single and double quote. I am asking about whether it's possible to escape characters in single quotes or not? And why only backslash is allowed to escape?

Comment: What is the expected form?

Comment: @sawa Most of the books/references says that diff b/w double quote and single quote is that there is no character escaping in single quotes... but it seems that '\\' is escaped. so most of the references are wrong I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only characters that needs to be escaped in a single quoted string are `'\\'` (for backslash `\`) and `'\''` (for single quote `'` itself).

Comment: and also '\1', '\2', and so on to call Regexp match array, i believe.

Comment: thanx for the answer... So there is no other way to escape other characters in single quotes?

Comment: @UandI I don't think so.

Comment: @sawa what I meant was, you also use \ to get the first, second, ..match string in a sub, gsub, and maybe tr also when you replace the match given in the first argument.

Comment: @styd This question/answer is about what needs to be escaped. It is not about how a backslash is used (other than for escaping). Your comment is out of the context. And your wording "also" contradicts with your latter comment.