# How to process file path?

Tags: ruby, file, path

I've a module inside an environment I use that, when I choose a file from a File Dialog, store the path inside a variable (let say var `path`).

I need than to get the list of all files within path and store it into an array.

So what I've tried is:

```
list = Dir[path + "*"]
```

the fact is that path is somethings like this:

```
D:\Google Drive\Samples\Black Octopus Sound\Drums - Kicks\
```

and when I read it, the array is empty. It's due to the fact that the slash should be `/` instead of `\`. So I've do this:

```
path = path.gsub('\\','\/')
```

but the result is:

```
D:\/Google Drive\/Samples\/Black Octopus Sound\/Drums - Kicks\/
```

looks like path stored in the variable is:

```
D:\\Google Drive\\Samples\\Black Octopus Sound\\Drums - Kicks\\
```

is that normal? Because If I just print the path, it looks correct:

```
D:\Google Drive\Samples\Black Octopus Sound\Drums - Kicks\
```

is this the intended bahaviour of escaping path in Ruby? Am I wrong? How can I best manage this situation?

And why can't I write:

```
path = "D:\Google Drive\Samples\Black Octopus Sound\Drums - Kicks\"
```

but only:

```
path = "D:\Google Drive\Samples\Black Octopus Sound\Drums - Kicks\ " // notice the last empty space in the end
```

it says `unterminated string meets end of file`

Comment: Well, it says "unterminated string" because the ``\`` character is used for escaping, thus `\"` is how you write a double quote inside a double-quoted string. So the right way to write it would be `path = "D:\\Google Drive\\Samples\\Black Octopus Sound\\Drums - Kicks\\"`, which prints as ``D:\Google Drive\Samples\Black Octopus Sound\Drums - Kicks\``.

Comment: Because a backslash means something in an interpolated Ruby string.

Comment: Ruby doesn't need backslashes in filenames. It understands what the OS needs and treats forward slashes appropriately. The [IO documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-open) says: `Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb".` Use forward-slashes and make your life easier.

Comment: I'd recommend reading "[Backslashes in single quoted strings vs. double quoted strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/648156/128421)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\   means =>> Escapes the next metacharacter.
```

Meaning you cannot use backslash on windows as part of a glob, example.

```
 Dir["D:\foo*"] will not work, use Dir["D:/foo*"] instead.`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
path = 'D:\Google Drive\Samples\Black Octopus Sound\Drums - Kicks\'
```

Difference in quotes. `''` will automaticaly escape backslashes and `""` not.

Also you wrote:

> It's due to the fact that the slash should be / instead of \

Windows uses backslash in paths but as @theTinMan noticed, ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible.

Quote from [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-open)

> When specifying a Windows-style filename in a Ruby string, remember to
>   escape the backslashes

Also pretty simple example you can find [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Escape_sequences).

Comment: `C:/Users/Admin` *IS* correct. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-open, which specifically says: `Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb". `

Comment: @theTinMan Actualy I said that about windows itself not just about ruby. But you are right, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @theTinMan: no! If I use `list = Dir[path + "*"]` on path with `\`, the list is empty. I mean: if I have `path = "D:\\Google Drive\\Samples\\Black Octopus Sound\\Leviathan\\Drums - Kicks\\"` and I do `list = Dir[path + "*"]`, it returns `[]`

Comment: Instead, this works: `list = Dir["D:/Google Drive/Samples/Black Octopus Sound/Leviathan/Drums - Kicks/*"]` and returns the correct list