# String#split in Ruby not behaving as expected

Tags: ruby

```
File.open(path, 'r').each do |line| 
  row = line.chomp.split('\t')
  puts "#{row[0]}"
end
```

`path` is the path of file having content like name, age, profession, hobby

I'm expecting output to be name only but I am getting the whole line.

Why is it so?

Comment: Edit your question to include sample input and output - that will help people to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was not very clear

`split("\n")` - if you want to split by lines

`split` - if you want to split by spaces

and as I can understand, you do not need chomp, because it removes all the "\n"

Comment: sorry sir but how to accept 
nd i solved my problem actully i m using split('\t') instead if ("\t") single quotes that i m using that is wrong

Comment: To accept answer, you can click on check mark on the right side of the question.

To uprate answer, you can click on the triangle which is pointing upwards which also is on the right side of the answer. Good luck

Answer (score 5):

The question already has an accepted answer, but it's worth noting what the cause of the original problem was:

This is the problem part:

```
split('\t')
```

Ruby has several forms for quoted string, which have differences, usually useful ones.

Quoting from [Ruby Programming at wikibooks.org](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Alternate_quotes):

> ...double quotes are designed to
>   interpret escaped characters such as
>   new lines and tabs so that they appear
>   as actual new lines and tabs when the
>   string is rendered for the user.
>   Single quotes, however, display the
>   actual escape sequence, for example
>   displaying \n instead of a new line.

Read further in the linked article to see the use of `%q` and `%Q` strings. Or Google for "ruby string delimiters", or see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279270/which-style-of-ruby-string-quoting-do-you-favour).

So `'\t'` is interpreted as "backslash+t", whereas `"\t"` is a tab character.

`String#split` will also take a `Regexp`, which in this case might remove the ambiguity:

```
split(/\t/)
```

Comment: Yep your answer is way more precise. Because the guy was talking about lines and his question was not very clear I thought that he was looking for a way to split text by lines.