# Why do I get an error due to two backslashes \\?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, ruby-test

I am writing a test and verifying some data. It's failing due to the two `\\` I get in the expected data string.

My test code is:

```
actual_string.should eq 'Today is Tuesday.\n It is third day of the week.'
```

When I execute this code, I get an error saying the actual data does not match the expected data.

The actual data is:

```
'Today is Tuesday.\n It is third day of the week.'
```

The expected data is:

```
'Today is Tuesday.\\n It is third day of the week.'
```

Not sure from where is that extra slash '\' is coming from in the expected data. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Use double quotes `"` - the backslash in your assertion is a literal backslash when inside single quotes.

Comment: @NeilSlater that's an answer, isn't it? ;)

Comment: So what is the main difference between single and double quotes. Ruby supports both right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279270/which-style-of-ruby-string-quoting-do-you-favour

Answer (score 1):

use "Text" - double quotes....

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other languages (e.g. Python, JavaScript etc.), Ruby uses different escape sequences in  single-quoted and double-quoted strings.

Single-quoted strings only support `\'` and `\\`. Everything else is treated literally. So, `'\n'` is two characters `\` and `n`, not a single new line character.

To use the new line character, enclose your string into double quotes:

```
actual_string.should eq "Today is Tuesday.\n It is third day of the week."
```

This will fix your test.